# Upload image from Isolated Storage to Facebook (WP7)

Tags: windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to upload an image from IsolatedStorage (Windows Phone 7) to facebook using the C# Facebook SDK.

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
            const string fileName = "image.jpg";
        IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(fileName))
            {
                IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);

                var photo = new WriteableBitmap(0, 0).LoadJpeg(fileStream);
                //photo.SetSource(fileStream);


                var mediaObject = new FacebookMediaObject
                                      {
                                          FileName = fileName,
                                          ContentType = "image/jpeg",
                                      };
                mediaObject.SetValue(photostream?);

            }

        var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;



        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
   {
        { "message", "the message" },
        { "link", "" },
        { "picture", "mediaobject.IMAGEHERE!" },
        { "name", "the name" },
        { "caption", "the caption" },
        { "description", "the descrption" },
        { "privacy", new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "value",  "ALL_FRIENDS" }
            }
        }
    };

        fb.PostAsync("me/feed", parameters, HttpMethod.Post);
```

This obviously doesn't work.. I need to know how I can get the image from IsolatedStorage into a format I can send to facebook..

Any help would be great, if you need anything else, please just ask.

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 0):

just change the "picture" to "source" in the parameters array and I think it will work

Comment: Yeah - I get that but i need to get the image into a workable object yet so that the facebook sdk can handle it..

Comment: Its just binary image data, you post it as multipart form data and FB will handle it automatically.